# VBA to Click Dropdown Link in IE without Name/ID

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to click a link on a company webpage through VBA. The issue is that the HTML doesn't have a Name or ID. I have seen many different scenarios on this site, and I have been attempting them, but I cannot seem to click this link.

I cannot share the site because it is a company intranet site, but I will share the section of HTML, and my code attempts.

Here is the HTML. It should be known that the link is only accessible by hovering over a menu.

```
 <li title="vendor" class="current"><a class="sf-with-ul" href="javascript:void(0);">Vendor A/P Inquiry<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>
  <ul style="width: 7.68em; float: none; display: none; visibility: hidden;">
   <li title="Vendor Invoice Inquiry Thru Browser" style="width: 100%; float: left; white-space: normal;"><a style="width: auto; float: none;" href="javascript:top.pageFrame.processSelection('VRJA');">Vendor A/P Inquiry</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Here is a screenshot of it, in case it is easier to read this way...
[image: HTML Screenshot]

**EDIT:** The parent item that I would hover over to display the link I need is the line `<li title="vendor" class="current">`

This is a few of my attempts at clicking this link (which is highlighted blue in the HTML Screenshot)

Attempt 1:

```
 Dim link As Object
            Dim doc As Object

            Set doc = ieApp.document

            For Each link In doc.Links
            Debug.Print link.innerText
            If link.innerText = "Vendor A/P Inquiry" Then
            link.Click
            Exit For
            End If
            Next link
```

Attempt 2:

```
  Set ieAnchors = ieApp.document.anchors
                For Each Anchor In ieAnchors
                    If Anchor.href = "javascript:top.pageFrame.processSelection('VRJA');" Then
                        Anchor.Click
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next Anchor
```

Attempt 3:

```
Set buttonclick = ieApp.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each element In buttonclick
    If element.href = "javascript:top.pageFrame.processSelection('VRJA');" Then element.Click
Next element
```

I can navigate the website fine until I get to this link.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I feel like I'm going in circles trying the same solutions over and over.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title='Vendor Invoice Inquiry Thru Browser'][href='javascript:top.pageFrame.processSelection('VRJA');']").Click
```

Though it sounds like you may have to click a parent item first to display this?

As you mention on hovering you may need to find the correct element to apply a FireEvent to e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title='Vendor']").FireEvent "onmouseover"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try this method I am getting an error that says "Method querySelector of object JScriptTypeInfo failed" I'm not familiar with what the JScriptTypeInfo is, any ideas?

Comment: yes.. it doesnt like the selector href='javascript:top.pageFrame.processSelection('VRJA');.... one moment and I will adjust.

Comment: try the amended version. Also try with just ie.document.querySelector("[title='Vendor Invoice Inquiry Thru Browser']").Click

Comment: Same error when trying the querySelector line alone. Perhaps it would work if I first queued the FireEvent. in order to do the FireEvent mouse hover, do you know how I would get the element? It has a title - "vendor" but I'm not aware of a getElementsByTitle method? It may be worth noting that when hovering, the class changes to "current sfHover" and visibility changes to "visible"

Comment: Hi, same problem with: 

ie.document.querySelector("[title='Vendor Invoice Inquiry Thru Browser']").Click ? I have edited a version for your other element. You could try different FireEvents or even just .Click

Comment: Also, based on some of the searching I was doing, could the querySelector be having an issue if the links are within a frame? I think they are, but honestly I'm not that experienced with it, so I'm not positive.

Comment: Can you share the link? If iframe/frame/form was an issue there would likely be an element not found error (once javascript error cleared out the way)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment. I tried your latest comment and then I just receive an "Object Required" error. Do I need to Dim the querySelector or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180058/discussion-between-qharr-and-tboulz).